# How to select rows starting with a particular string in R?

Tags: r, variables, dplyr, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I have data like so:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("James", "jonathan", "Abel", "Cynthia", "Cornelius", "alex"))

      name
     James
  jonathan
      Abel
   Cynthia
 Cornelius
      alex
```

I want to select rows where `name` doesn't begin with "A" or "J". Expected result:

```
      name
   Cynthia
 Cornelius
```

I'd like a simple `dplyr` solution.

Comment: `df[!grepl("^(?i)a|j", df$name), ]` may solve your problem. The `grepl`-part can be wrapped inside `dplyr::filter()`

Comment: You have received several helpful answers to this question, but FYI for future questions it is generally expected that you show some effort at solving the problem yourself.  This is presented like (charitably) a home work question or (less charitably) a task for a coding service.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Perhaps you should spend less time making assumptions. https://www.oprahdaily.com/life/a29474453/how-to-find-inner-peace/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grepl` with `filter`. `"^[A|J]"` matches strings that start with an A or a J, while `ignore.case = TRUE` indicates that both lower and uppercases letters are matched. Since you want to keep the value that do *not* start with A or J, you can use `!` to invert the selection:

```r
library(dplyr)
df |>
  filter(!grepl("^[A|J]", name, ignore.case = TRUE))

#        name
# 1   Cynthia
# 2 Cornelius
```

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to use `dplyr::filter()` in tandem with a case insensitive `stringr::str_starts()`:

```r
df |>
    dplyr::filter(
        !stringr::str_starts(name, "(?i)A|J")
    )
```

The `(?i)` tells it to be insensitive to the case and the `|` says to look for either `a/A` or `j/J`.

Output:

```
       name
1   Cynthia
2 Cornelius
```

Answer (score 2):

In base R, you can use `grep` to index (with `invert = TRUE` and `ignore.case = TRUE`):

```
df[grep("^A|^J", df$name, invert = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE),]

#[1] "Cynthia"   "Cornelius"
```

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` doesn't have any special string functions. You just want to use `filter` with a test to see if the firs letter is not A or J. Here's one way, converting the `name` to upper case for our test, using `substr` to extract the first character, and then testing if it is not J or A:

```
library(dplyr)
df |>
  filter(!substr(toupper(name), 1, 1) %in% c("J", "A"))
```

You could write the test many other ways, using `grepl` or `startsWith` from base, using `stringr::str_detect` or `stringi::stri_detect`, etc.